# Конкатенировать все следущие элементы

Tags: javascript

Имеется input, который должен разделить имя и фамилию. Для этого я использую метод split. Иногда, у человека может быть двойное имя(как и фамилия, но в рамках задачи нужно только имя) и он может ввести это имя в форму через пробелы(например, Пупкин Вася Сергей). Как сделать так, что бы все остальные следующие элементы конкатенировались в имя?

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')

input.oninput = () => {

  const [firstName, lastName] = input.value.split(' ')
  console.log(firstName, lastName)
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собираем остальные кусочки в один массив и объединяем его обратно в строку по пробелу:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

input.oninput = () => {
  let [firstName, ...lastName] = input.value.split(' ');
  lastName = lastName ? lastName.join(' ').trim() : '';
  
  result.innerHTML = `Имя: "${firstName}", фамилия: "${lastName}"`;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" /><br />
<span id='result'></span>
```